# NoClassDefFoundError when class is in JBoss AS7 WAR WEB-INF/classes folder

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I'm using JBoss AS7.  I get a ClassNotFoundException when attempting to deploy my app - looks like it's not finding JMSException

```
09:54:53,166 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myapp-maventest.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myapp-maventest.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "myapp-maventest.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:121)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [:1.6.0_26]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class com.mycompany.myapp.common.jms.servlets.StationLogout
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.EEModuleClassDescription$DefaultConfigurator.configure(EEModuleClassDescription.java:144)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.EEClassConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEClassConfigurationProcessor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:115)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JMSException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791) [:1.6.0_26]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:65)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JMSException from [Module "deployment.myapp-maventest.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:330)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:307)
    at org.jboss.modules.Conc
```

JMSException.class is not in /modules/javax/jms .  I have this class in a jar file - javaee-api-6.0.jar .   I copied this jar file to /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib , but I'm still receiving this ClassNotFoundException.

I need help debugging.  One thing I tried - I thought maybe the /modules/javax module JBoss was loading was conflicting with my javaee-api-6.0.jar file - so I tried to exclude it with a src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml file

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="javax.jms" />
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

but I still get the same NoClassDefFoundError.  Any advice on how to fix?

Comment: what is your war file structure? where is the position of your jar in this war?

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the module of JMS in the jbossas7?By default in the standalone.xml isn't enabled.You have to edit the standalone.xml you are using and then it will load the jms and the implementation(aka Hornetq).